# longtable inside enumerate

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, longtable, enumerate

When I have a longtable left-aligned inside an enumerate, it isn't indented properly. For example

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item text

% \setlength\LTleft{\itemindent}
% \setlength\LTright{\fill}
\begin{longtable}[l]{lll}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
l & m & n \\
\end{longtable}

text

\end{enumerate}
```

produces

[image: example output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overriding the placement parameters by saying `\begin{longtable}[l]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item text

\setlength\LTleft{\leftmargin}
\setlength\LTright{\fill}
\begin{longtable}{@{}lll@{}}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
l & m & n \\
\end{longtable}

text

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note `@{}` to remove the left and right paddings.

I used `showframe` just for showing the text block margins.

[image]